# Query using "CASE WHEN" statement in WHERE causes QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST

Tags: jpa, hql, spring-data, jpql, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to make a query using Spring Data, but I cannot make it work:

```
@Query(SELECT t FROM Thing t WHERE name LIKE :name AND CASE WHEN (:minVal <= 0) THEN TRUE ELSE (val <= :minVal) END AND CASE WHEN (:maxVal <= 0) THEN TRUE ELSE (val >= :maxVal) END)
Page<Thing> getThings(@Param("name") String name, @Param("maxVal") int maxVal, @Param("minVal") minVal);
```

StackTrace:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST
>   node: CASE near line 1, column 49 [SELECT t FROM Thing t WHERE name
>   LIKE :name AND CASE WHEN (:minVal <= 0) THEN TRUE ELSE (val <=
>   :minVal) END AND CASE WHEN (:maxVal <= 0) THEN TRUE ELSE (val >=
>   :maxVal) END]     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1750)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1683)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:331)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor40.invoke(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:334)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy83.createQuery(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:78)
>     ... 207 more
>
> Caused by:
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST
>   node: CASE near line 1, column 49 [SELECT t FROM Thing t WHERE name
>   LIKE :name AND CASE WHEN (:minVal <= 0) THEN TRUE ELSE (val <=
>   :minVal) END AND CASE WHEN (:maxVal <= 0) THEN TRUE ELSE (val >=
>   :maxVal) END]     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:91)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:109)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:284)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:206)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:126)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:88)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:190)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1800)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:328)

I'm using this because I want to make a longer query using five filters at least, and I want to simplify the effort of doing the filter combinations making differents querys.

Don't know if there is a different (and better) way to do what I want, glad to ear it if it is.

Thank you.

EDIT: Using native query works fine, but isn't compatible with pagination yet...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like Hibernate cannot evaluate the result of a CASE expression when it returns a boolean literal directly. A workaround is to make the CASE expression part of another expression, e.g. by comparing it to another boolean literal.

So instead of:

```
... AND CASE WHEN (:minVal <= 0) THEN TRUE ELSE (val <= :minVal) END
```

Try:

```
... AND (CASE WHEN (:minVal <= 0) THEN TRUE ELSE (val <= :minVal) END) = TRUE
```

But looking at that expression, wouldn't it be simpler to just do:

```
... AND (:minVal <= 0 OR val <= :minVal)
```

Is it not equivalent?

Comment: I should have been gone for a beer to think simple, as you suggested. Yeah, the last option it's quite effective to do the same as case. And yes, seems that Hibernate it's not able to do what I wanted... Thank you!