# Spring Hibernate Query syntax exception when using "case when"

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hql

The query works as native query in PostgreSQL. But fails when passing it to be used in Spring Data JPA @Query, with Hibernate. Which would be the correct syntax to write the query?

```
@Repository
public interface ProcessoJudicialRepository extends JpaRepository<ProcessoJudicial, Long> {

  @Query("select p from ProcessoJudicial p where"
      + " case when :numero is not null then (p.numero = :numero) else true end"
      + " and case when :advogadoId is not null then (p.advogado_id = :advogadoId) else true end"
      + " and case when :assuntoId is not null then (p.assuntoId = :assuntoId) else true end"
      + " and case when :modalidadeId is not null then (p.modalidade_id = :modalidadeId) else true end")
  Page<ProcessoJudicial> find(@Param("numero") String numero, @Param("advogadoId") Long advogadoId,
      @Param("assuntoId") Long assuntoId, @Param("modalidadeId") Long modalidadeId,
      Pageable pageable);
}
```

This exception is launched:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node: case near line 1, column 77 [select p from com.rcsoyer.servicosjuridicos.domain.ProcessoJudicial p where case when :numero is not null then (p.numero = :numero) else true end and case when :advogadoId is not null then (p.advogado_id = :advogadoId) else true end and case when :assuntoId is not null then (p.assuntoId = :assuntoId) else true end and case when :modalidadeId is not null then (p.modalidade_id = :modalidadeId) else true end]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:272)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:153)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:553)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:662)
    ... 125 common frames omitted
```

I tried the solution for this other question

[Question appointed as solution for mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25710317/query-using-case-when-statement-in-where-causes-querysyntaxexception-unexpect)

Although that didn't work in my case.

Comment: actually you cannot use parameter as `case when :advogadoId`. you need to think for any alernative

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Query using "CASE WHEN" statement in WHERE causes QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25710317/query-using-case-when-statement-in-where-causes-querysyntaxexception-unexpect)

Comment: Why I cannot use it, @Nidhi257?

Comment: @Nidhi257 actually the JPA spec says you can have a parameter within a CASE expression.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find a clean and easy way of writing the query with "CASE WHEN", so I changed to use "AND" and "OR". Has the exact same effect that I had before, but now works in both ways, direct at Postgres and also with Hibernate.

The final code is:

```
  @Query("from #{#entityName} p where"
      + " ((:numero is not null and p.numero = :numero) or (:numero is null))"
      + " and ((:advogadoId is not null and p.advogado.id = :advogadoId) or (:advogadoId is null))"
      + " and ((:assuntoId is not null and p.assunto.id = :assuntoId) or (:assuntoId is null))"
      + " and ((:modalidadeId is not null and p.modalidade.id = :modalidadeId) or (:modalidadeId is null))")
  Page<ProcessoJudicial> query(@Param("numero") String numero, @Param("advogadoId") Long advogadoId,
      @Param("assuntoId") Long assuntoId, @Param("modalidadeId") Long modalidadeId, Pageable pageable);
```

Although, if someone knows the correct way of writing the query, maybe in an easier and cleaner way, using "CASE WHEN", or even an improvement in the query above, I would be glad to know.

Comment: its a dirty way but that your answer help my project! thank you for sharing

Answer (score 0):

Column 77 of that JPQL is the opening "case" keyword. The [JPQL BNF](http://www.datanucleus.org:15080/products/accessplatform_5_1/jpa/query.html#jpql_bnf) (as shown in the JPA spec) is expecting a simple conditional expression, and "case expression" is not that in the JPA spec.

```
simple_cond_expression ::= 
    comparison_expression | 
    between_expression | 
    in_expression | 
    like_expression | 
    null_comparison_expression |
    empty_collection_comparison_expression | 
    collection_member_expression | 
    exists_expression
```

So you could have a WHERE clause with something like

```
(case_expression) = some_value
```

but not

```
(case_expression)
```

on its own.

Note that not all JPA providers have this restriction that Hibernate has, and can indeed evaluate it fine (but that is an extension to the JPA spec, e.g DataNucleus JPA).